# package data not installed from python .egg file

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm trying to include some data files in a python package using the setuptools package_data option. I'm then accessing the files with pkg_resources. This works perfectly when the python .egg file is installed as-is (i.e. still zipped). But when the egg file is unzipped during installation, the data files are not installed.

In other words, if I run:

```
python setup.py bdist_egg
cd dist
sudo easy_install -z EnrichPy-0.1.001-py2.6.egg
```

then the egg file is installed (with the data safely zipped inside) and everything works.

On the other hand, if I run

```
sudo easy_install -Z EnrichPy-0.1.001-py2.6.egg
```

then the data files are not installed. I have a directory called 
`EnrichPy-0.1.001-py2.6.egg/enrichpy/` under dist-packages, but it contains only my source files, not my data files.

Can anyone suggest what I need to do to get the package_data files to be installed when easy_install unzips the egg file?

Notes:

The package is available at http://github.com/roban/EnrichPy

I can test it by running:
    import enrichpy.yields
    enrichpy.yields.Data_vdHG().data
If that exits without errors, then pkg_resources is finding the installed data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, thanks to help from P.J. Eby on the distutils-sig email list:

http://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2010-November/017054.html

Just needed to rename files to avoid the '..' string.